# How can I remove lines which contain '*' using core Java?

Tags: java

How can I remove lines which contains `*` using core Java, for example:-

```
hello how are you. 
what are you  * doing.
```

In the above example, I have to remove the entire line `what are you * doing` which contains `*` in the line.

Comment: something like this: `for(String line: lines) { if(line.indexOf('*') == -1) lineList.add(line); else { /* ignore line */ } }`

Comment: did you read out the lines from a file or are that Strings you get one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work fine for your problem:

```
    String s="hello how are you. \nwhat are you  * doing.";
    String p[]=s.split("\n");
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    for(String n:p)
    {
        if(n.contains("*"))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            sb.append(n);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work ..

```
    String str="hello how are you. \nwhat are you  * doing.";
    str.replace("*","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java so if there's something wrong pls correct me, but I would suggest if you read out of a file:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream)); 


String s = bf.readLine();

if(s!=null)
{
   if(s.contains("*"))
   {
        s="";
   }
   else
   {
   //work with the rest of your line stored in String
   }
}
```

to put it in a loop (e.g. `for` or `while`)

Comment: `java.io.BufferedReader` has not _default_ (empty) constructor, needs a `Reader`. Besides that, `s` could be `null`, if you reach the end of stream. You should check on that.

Comment: @Albert changed it, I hope it fits now ;)

Comment: @Tom sry i misstyped ;) I corrected it and formated my code

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use string methods contains.

```
String s="something *";
if(s.contains(*)) 
{
   s=""; 
}
else
{
   ///do else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 lists as per this code snippet:

```java
List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList(
    "hello how are you.",
    "what are you  * doing.");
            
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        
for (String item : originalList) {
    if (!item.contains("*"))
        filteredList.add(item);
}
```